# Rete Library giving error with React JS : ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined

Tags: reactjs, rete

Rete library is giving this below error upon installing. Below is the error that I am getting.

```
(anonymous function)
node_modules/rete/build/rete.esm.js:413
  410 | value: function () {
  411 |   var _build = _asyncToGenerator(
  412 |   /*#__PURE__*/
> 413 |   regeneratorRuntime.mark(function _callee(node) {
  414 |     return regeneratorRuntime.wrap(function _callee$(_context) {
  415 |       while (1) {
  416 |         switch (_context.prev = _context.next) {
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Here I have installed rete along with some other rete plugins as shown below.

```
npm i --save rete rete-react-render-plugin rete-connection-plugin rete-area-plugin
```

Rete Library has some dependencies which could be solved by pasting the below line in the index.html file of your react js project.

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/rete@1.0.0-alpha.9/build/rete.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/rete-vue-render-plugin@0.2.0/build/vue-render-plugin.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/rete-connection-plugin@0.1.2/build/connection-plugin.min.js"></script>
```